# Number obtained by reversing digits. Find the value satisfying a condition.

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be two-digit integers such that $b$ is obtained by reversing the digits of $a$. The integers $a$ and $b$ satisfy $a^2-b^2=m^2$ for some positive integer $m$. Which could be value of $m$?

a) $30$
b) $31$
c) $32$
d) $33$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. You will find that people on this site will be significantly faster to help you if you do that; that way, we know exactly what help you need.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself on how to make progress with this? It is an interesting little question which requires you to put a few pieces of information together - you'll learn more by working it out for yourself than by reading any answer I might give.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a$ and $b$ have two digits, write $a=10x+y$ and $b=10y+x$ ($x$ and $y$ are the digits). Now expand $a^2-b^2$, you find:
$$
a^2-b^2=99(x^2-y^2)=m^2
$$

As a consequence, $11$ must divide $m$, which gives the solution (case d).

---

If you want to find $a$ and $b$, remark that you need $x^2-y^2=11$ which occurs for $x=6$ and $y=5$.

Answer (score 0):

33

a=65

b=56

a^2-b^2=1089

33^2=1089